# Are there example pages similar to man pages?

Tags: linux, unix

```
man find
```

opens up the man page for find in my pager.

Is there something like

```
example find
```

that would print

```
find /usr/lib -name "stdint.h"
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand you correctly: Are you just looking for examples for common commands? Note that many manpages have a section dedicated to examples.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. Is there a quick way to just print the examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Is there a quick way to just print the examples?**

Yes.

```
 man find | perl -ne 'print if /^EXAMPLE/.../^[A-Z]/'
```

Similar solutions must exist using `awk` etc

```
 man find | awk '/^EXAMPLES/,/^EXIT/ { print }'
```

Comment: Notes: On Mac OS X, the specified `perl` invocation fails because the output of man actually contains `E\bEX\bXA\bAM\bMP\bPL\bLE\bE', where `\b` is backspace; if you do can pass those backspace characters to `perl`, it works. However, `perl` doesn't seem to interpret the actual sequence `\b` like that, so the only way I've found is with bash's `$''` quoting: `man find | perl -ne $'print if /^E\bEX\bXA\bAM\bMP\bPL\bLE\bE/.../^[A-Z]/'`.

Comment: Continued: I can't get the awk example to work; `EXIT` doesn't occur right after the `EXAMPLES` section in OS X, and `awk` on OS X doesn't work with `[A-Z]`, but at least it does recognize `\b`.

Comment: You can probably prefix the command with `TERM=something` to prevent `man` inserting special formatting characters. Perhaps man on OSX has some options fo this?